# Significato di "attaccare una festa" in questa frase

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Non c’era nessuno delle parti del Pavaglione che potessi dirmelo amico, ma non avevo neanche dei nemici, salvo forse un balordo che senza avanzar niente da me e soltanto per far lo spiritoso m’**aveva attaccato una festa** a Manera, ma m’abbrivò solo a parole.

Non riesco a capire bene il senso dell'espressione "attaccare una festa" che appare in questo testo. Ho cercato il  [vocabolo "festa" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/festa) e ho trovato questa accezione:

> *fare la f. a qualcuno*, o *a un animale* (soprattutto animali da cortile), ammazzarlo, oppure, riferito a persona, conciarlo male, ridurlo in cattivo stato;

La mia domanda è: è anche questo il significato dell'espressione che appare nella frase sopra citata, cioè, "m'aveva attaccato una festa" vuol dire "m'aveva ridotto in cattivo stato"?

Answer (score 2):

Sono quasi sicuro che in questo caso si tratti di una variazione arcaica o dialettale della locuzione "**attaccare briga**".

Quindi si potrebbe parafrasare con "**ha attaccato briga con me**".